# Define application properties on build using Spring Boot and Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that uses a database. I have the local configuration in the application.properties file. I understand it is possible to change the values when I build the project with maven. I want to set the production values (db on AWS).

Here is application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=${db.url:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb}
spring.datasource.username=${db.username:localusername}
spring.datasource.password=${db.password:localpassword}
```

I would like to change the values when I run. This will create a docker image.

```
mvn package docker:build
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, should you do it no you shouldn't. You want the same artifact delivered to different environments. You don't want to rebuild the application just because you are changing environments. Use spring profiles to load additional properties (spring boot supports this out of the box) that way you build once and just reconfigure the `spring.profiles.active` property.

Comment: Thx for the advice. I found this question that helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007686/how-can-i-provide-different-database-configurations-with-spring-boot